# sql not returning output after applying joins and filter

Tags: sql

My query which has no returning output.Schema is trial

```
    select emp.name,emp.id,emp.id_type,record.salary
    from emp
    join record on emp.id = record.sal_id;
```

Comment: It will not return an output obviously, writing query that way is not a good practice.

Comment: As we do not know your data and you did not post any sample of it, it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the query below to get your desired output.

```
    select e.name,e.id,e.id_type,r.salary
    from trial.emp e
    join trial.record r on e.id = r.sal_id;
```